# Do Typescript Arrays allocate memory for empty indices?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, memory

I am trying to duplicate a portion of a server side database for processing in a typescript web application.  I need to access the various records by their integer ID within typescript.  One issue I see is that the indices might not be contiguous, nor start with 0 (in fact they could start with a value much higher than zero if a portion of the database had been deleted).

Given the following code:

```
let a: Array<number> = new Array<number>();
a[10] = 1;
a[11] = 2;
```

If I inspect a in Chrome I see:

```
(12) [empty × 10, 1, 2]
```

which leads me to believe that I have allocated memory for 12 values, but am only using the last 2.  This is not a big deal for small starting indices, but if I have a first index in the millions, and am using larger objects in the array, it can become a significant memory issue.

Am I correct in assuming that the memory is being allocated even for non-used indices?  And if so, what would be a better container to use that allows for non-contiguous indices?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the implementation of the JavaScript runtime, but generally speaking, sparse arrays only allocate memory for elements that are actually in use.

To my knowledge, Chrome for example stores sparse arrays as a dictionary internally, which is why you may also experience different performance characteristics between sparse and full arrays.